# How to put Tables inside a "Master Table"?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013

I've been getting a beating by Excel recently! :)

I want to make a "Master Table" that comprehends all of the other tables in my workbook. The problem I'm facing is that if I just refer to the cells, the new rows I insert won't show in my Master Table since by referring I'm only doing so to specific cells. Therefore, can I refer to an entire table? I have 10~ tables that I want to put inside my "Master Table".

I'm sorry that I don't know the correct terminology for the words, but I hope I made the question clear enough for understanding. Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: It is important to know what version of Excel are you using in order to be able to answer this question. Are the "other tables" formatted as tables or are you just calling them that?

Comment: I use Excel 2007 and 2013. They are formatted as tables, not just calling them names. :)

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, you are trying to create a single table which combines the data from all the other tables?

Comment: That's exactly it! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way I know (I'm sure there are others) of doing this is to utilise the free Excel addin from Microsoft, PowerQuery.

You set up each data table and then merge queries of all tables to produce the master. As you change the data tables, a simple refresh of the master table will update it and include everything you need.

UPDATE: I'm rather rusty on the old way of doing this but it should work. As long as you have a common column you can use as an index, you can use data queries against tables in your workbook, just make sure you set the query up as read-only (default is read/write which will fail since the workbook will always be open when you are running the query). Still make sure you format your data as "Tables" in Excel so that they auto-expand otherwise you need to do clever things with naming your data areas. Then you will need to dust off your SQL skills to join the tables together in the query builder.

Comment: Julian, I'm sure the method you've suggested works. However unfortunately here in my work we have Windows XP, which isn't supported by PowerQuery, something I found out when I was installing it. To me it'd be optimal if I could use the solution both in my work and in my personal computer (Win 8.1 with Office 2013). Is there a way?

Comment: Oh oh! You really MUST get them to move off, XP is now fully unsupported unless you pay Microsoft a SHED-LOAD of money! Quite frankly I'm surprised Excel 2013 even runs on XP :(

Comment: Actually the 2013 is installed only in my personal computer, which runs Windows 8.1.

Regarding the update edit, it sounds something a little bit out of my league (SQL), so I believe from now on I will just use my personal PC with PowerQuery to work on the workbook, should be easier! Thank you for taking the time to answer the question!

Comment: No problem. I think you are wise to do it that way. It is vastly easier though you will still tear your hair out getting to grips with the Microsoft PQ syntax! :) Keep going though because it really is worth it.